# Sharing folder in OneDrive in office365

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business

I have shared a folder with onedrive with others in Office365. After couple of days i have removed the user from my shared folder however the user still able to see the folder. Is this browser cache or Do i have to wait hours or days to get this impact?. Please advise, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the sharing with user at folder level then it should remove it immediately. couple of things to make sure.

- check the folder properties and see if that folder still shared with the user.[How do I see who I'm sharing a document with?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-documents-or-folders-in-Office-365-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c?CTT=1&CorrelationId=33226dbc-4f4c-4a0e-9af7-b6f25de8ae34&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- also may be user have the permission /shareing on the root of that folder which give them automatic permission to lower end.

Comment: Hi Waqas. Thanks for your response. I have edit the question. The permission is removed immediately however the user who has removed from shared folder is still able to see the folder that is being shared